# Windows device manager data screwed up

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, boot-camp

I have Windows running on a Macbook via Bootcamp.

Got 3 drives: 2 for Windows (1 as bootdrive and 1 for storage), and 1 for Mac.

Recently I've upgraded to Yosemite and lost the storage partition (NTFS) in the process.

Below is my device manager data. If you look at the highlighted parts, Disk info is different to Volume info.

[image: Screwed up Disk Management data]

Why is there a difference of about 350 gigs?

Comment: I've stated the problem that I have lost a partition. I've stated the steps as to how I lost them. And I asked how to fix my problem. I dont get what else should go into the question to make it **clear**.

Comment: Where have you stated it?  It's not in the question

Comment: `Recently I've upgraded to Yosemite and lost the storage partition. Why is there a difference of about 350 gigs?`.

Answer (score 1):

I did some poking around the internet and noticed that some other people ran into weird issues with bootcamp when they updated to Yosemite. What's important to remember is that Bootcamp is not really supported by Apple. We constantly run into problems related to poorly written drivers. What you are looking at is a driver error. The storage driver is not detecting the drive properly. In order to fix it, apple will need to patch the driver and release a new version.

When you upgraded to Yosemite, did you wipe out the bootcamp install and rebuild it? From the sound of it, you already had a bootcamp install before you upgraded. you could try rebuilding your bootcamp environment, but that is a really drastic measure that won't necessarily fix a driver issue.

You could also try resetting the partition size record.

1. Load into MacOS and resize the Windows partition to be under 350GB (try 300GB).
2. Reboot into Bootcamp and see if the partition size is reporting properly.
3. Go back to MacOS and resize the Windows partition to the full size of the drive.
4. Go back to Bootcamp and check the partition.

Hope that helps.